# Print varible names in table() with 2 binary variables in R

Tags: r

I'm sure I'll kick myself for not being able to figure this out, but when you have a table with 2 variables (i.e. cross-tab) and both are binary or otherwise have the same levels, how can you make R show which variable is displayed row-wise and which is column-wise?

For example:

```
> table(tc$tr, tc$fall_term)

       0    1
  0 1569  538
  1    0  408
```

is a little confusing because it's not immediately obvious which is which. Of course, I checked out `?table` but I don't see an option to do this, at least not a logical switch that doesn't require me to already know which is which.

I tried `ftable` but had the same problem.

The output I want would be something like this:

```
> table(tc$tr, tc$fall_term)
             tr    tr 
               0    1
fallterm     0 1569  538
fallterm     1    0  408
```

or

```
> table(tc$tr, tc$fall_term)
    fallterm    fallterm 
           0    1
tr     0 1569  538
tr     1    0  408
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?  If you need some labels, then use `paste` to create the unique identifier before doing the `table` or you may need `names(dimnames(tbl)) <- list('row', 'col')` etc.

Comment: did you try to use the `dnn` option : `dnn=c('tr','fall_term')` ?

Comment: @etienne `dnn` might work, but I don't know what to put for the values

Comment: @akrun I'll add expected output to the question, thanks

Comment: @etienne Make that an answer, I didn’t know about that option.

Comment: @etienne ah, ok, the updated version of your comment works. Of course, it assumes that's the correct order, but I suppose it would make sense since that's the order they are entered in `table`. If you want to post that as a solution I'll accept it.

Comment: @akrun Right, sorry about leaving off the expected output. I don't think `dimnames` will work for a dataframe like this... I tried it 2 ways and this was the result `> dimnames(tc$tr) <- list("tr")`
Error in dimnames(tc$tr) <- list("tr") : 'dimnames' applied to non-array
`> dimnames(tc$tr, tc$fall_term) <- list("tr", "fall_term")`
Error in `dimnames<-`(`*tmp*`, tc$fall_term, value = list("tr", "fall_term")) : 
  3 arguments passed to 'dimnames<-' which requires 2

Comment: I am not talkiing about the original dataset.  But the `tbl` result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `dnn` option :

```
table(df$tr,df$fall_term) # impossible to tell the difference

     0  1
  0 18 33
  1 15 34

table(df$tr,df$fall_term,dnn=c('tr','fall_term')) # you have the names
   fall_term
tr   0  1
  0 18 33
  1 15 34
```

Note that it's easier (and safer) to do `table(df$tr,df$fall_term,dnn=colnames(df))`

Answer (score 1):

Check out `dimnames`, and in particular their `names`. I’m using another example here since I don’t have your data:

```
x = HairEyeColor[, , Sex = 'Male']

names(dimnames(x))
# [1] "Hair" "Eye"

names(dimnames(x)) = c('Something', 'Else')
x
#          Else
# Something Brown Blue Hazel Green
#     Black    32   11    10     3
#     Brown    53   50    25    15
#     Red      10   10     7     7
#     Blond     3   30     5     8
```

Comment: I don't think this would work when you're using 2 cols in a dataframe with more than 2 cols (and I don't want to stop to create a new object or name every one of my many columns).

Comment: > dimnames(tc$tr) <- list("tr") Error in dimnames(tc$tr) <- list("tr") : 'dimnames' applied to non-array > dimnames(tc$tr, tc$fall_term) <- list("tr", "fall_term") Error in dimnames<-(*tmp*, tc$fall_term, value = list("tr", "fall_term")) : 3 arguments passed to 'dimnames<-' which requires 2

Comment: @Hack-R Look at my answer again: you need to use `names(dimnames(x))`, not just `dimnames(x)`. But this will still not work since you’re applying it to the wrong object: `tc$tr` doesn’t have `dimnames` the *output table* does. When you encounter errors like this, your first instinct should be to inspect the object in question — this would have told you why `dimnames(tc$tr)` doesn’t work.